# Fail to add a page controller to RBTabbedPageContainerViewController

Tags: redbeard-ios

I'm trying to create a simple TabBar Controller, but I fail to add pages to it.

```
class TabbedPageContainerViewController: RBTabbedPageContainerViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let success = addPageController(MapViewController(), withTitle: "Fancy Tab")

        print("addPageController: \(success)")
        print("pages: \(pageControllerCount)")
        print("first item: \(pageControllerAtIndex(0))")
    }

    ...
```

resulting in an empty white screen and the console output:

```
addPageController: true
pages: 0
first item: nil
```

`MapViewController` itself is a `RBPageViewController`:

```
class MapViewController: RBPageViewController, MGLMapViewDelegate {

    ...
```

`MapViewController` is properly instantiated. It's `viewDidLoad` fired, `viewDidAppear` did obviously not since it's not added to the tabbed page container.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it myself through instantiating both classes in the `TabbedPageContainerViewController` in the `applicationDidFinishLaunching`:

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
    let tabbedPageContainerViewController = TabbedPageContainerViewController()
    tabbedPageContainerViewController.addPageController(MapViewController(), withTitle: "Fancy Tab"))

    // present tabbed page controller
    window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds)
    window?.rootViewController = tabbedPageContainerViewController
    window?.makeKeyAndVisible()

    return true
}
```

But why is this necessary? Didn't I read somewhere that Redshift should be supposed to to such things "on the fly"?